# Почему `print(bool(264 % 20 != 2 and 4))` выдает true?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему `print(bool(264 % 20 != 2 and 4))` выдает true?

Answer (score 2):

Сначала вычисляем выражение внутри скобок:

- `264 % 20` равно `4`, так как `264` делится на `20` без остатка `13` раз, и остается `4`.
- Получаем: `4 != 2`, что эквивалентно `True`, так как `4` не равно `2`.

Далее смотрим всё выражение целиком

- Таким образом, `True and 4` , оба операнда истинные (`True` и *ненулевое число*).

Поэтому результат выражения `print(bool(264 % 20 != 2 and 4))` будет `True`.

Comment: А как тогда сделать, чтобы была проверка того что остаток отделения 264 на 20(то есть 4) не равен 2 и не равен 4?

Comment: ... not in (2, 4)

Comment: print(bool((264 % 20 != 2) and (264 % 20 != 4))). То есть как это код написать по другому

Comment: @Jaspper15325 Можно вынести в отдельную переменную `264 % 20`